# chef windows installed java service not working

Tags: java, windows, chef-infra

I'm trying to create a windows service that is running java with a jar.

The resource creating the service is:

```
service_name="Service"
service_file="C:\\chef_solo\\utils\\service-17.jar"
java_exe="#{java_home_win}\\bin\\java.exe"
binPath="#{java_exe} -jar #{service_file} "

execute "Installing #{service_name}" do
  command "sc create \"#{service_name}\" binPath= \"#{binPath}\" obj= \".\\#{gst_user}\" password= \"#{gst_pwd}\" start= auto displayname= \"GS Translation Service\""
  action :nothing
end
```

The service is created, but when is run, I get an error message saying:

```
Windows could not start the Service service on 192.168.0.10. Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

And I guess that this happens because when i run it by hand, it takes about 45 seconds until the service is up and the port is opened.
How can I make it wait? Or is there another issue I don't understand?

Thank you.

Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

The solution was on [Microsoft's support site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/824344/how-to-debug-windows-services):

> When a service starts, the service communicates to the Service Control Manager how long the service must have to start (the time-out period for the service). If the Service Control Manager does not receive a "service started" notice from the service within this time-out period, the Service Control Manager terminates the process that hosts the service.
>
> This time-out period is typically less than 30 seconds. If you do not adjust this time-out period, the Service Control Manager ends the process and the attached debugger while you are trying to debug.
>
> To adjust this time-out period, follow these steps:
>
> In Registry Editor, locate, and then right-click the following registry subkey:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
> ```
>
> Point to **New**, and then click **DWORD Value**.
>
> In the right pane of Registry Editor, notice that **New Value #1** (the name of a new registry entry) is selected for editing.
>
> Type **ServicesPipeTimeout** to replace **New Value #1**, and then press ENTER.
>
> Right-click the **ServicesPipeTimeout** registry entry that you created in step c, and then click **Modify**. The **Edit DWORD Value** dialog box appears.
>
> In the **Value data** text box, type **TimeoutPeriod**, and then click
>       OK
>
> Note: **TimeoutPeriod** is a placeholder for the value of the time-out period (in milliseconds) that you want to set for the service. For example, if you want to set the time-out period to 24 hours (86400000 milliseconds), type 86400000.
>
> Restart the computer. You must restart the computer for Service Control Manager to apply this change.